# Using Successor ML with SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I was pleasantly surprised when I saw that SML/NJ recently made some major changes in [version 110.79](http://smlnj.org/dist/working/110.79/110.79-README.html) which is part of a move towards something called Successor ML. This seems to be a cooperative venture between SML/NJ and MLton and bodes well for the future of SML.

However, I seem to encounter a weird bug (on 64-bit Windows 7) when I try to use some of the new features. To try it out, I wrote the following in a file called `sml_successor_test.sml`:

```
Control.succML := true;
val n = 123_456;
print (Int.toString n);
```

when I try to load it into the REPL using `use "C:\Programs\sml_successor_test.sml";` the compiler balks at the second line in the file (which uses a new type of number literal which should be enabled). But -- when I immediately run the exact same `use` command as before -- it works.

If first use `Control.succML := true;` in the REPL and then use `use` to load the file (after removing that line from the file) it *does* work. On the other hand, if I just fire up SML, enable `succML`, and then have the assignment `val n = 123_456;` directly in the REPL, it fails the first time but then works.

To sum up -- there seems to be a weird lag between when `Control.succML := true` is evaluated and when it takes effect, a lag which happens in some contexts but not others. Any idea what is behind this and any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me on Mac OS X as well. What I did, though, was to use the `-Cparser.succ-ml=true` flag in my `sml` alias, which behaves as expected:

```
alias sml="rlwrap /usr/local/bin/sml -Cparser.succ-ml=true"
```

I forget now what's the Windows equivalent. You may have to create your own sml wrapper script and place it before the SML/NJ one in `PATH`.

Comment: Windows does have a way to create aliases -- but I found it more natural to take your idea of writing a wrapper script, which I will include as a second answer for Windows users.

Comment: Hmm, seems reasonable to have a quick way to choose between SML and SuccML. I might do that, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of the accepted answer. I used @IonutGStan 's idea of a wrapper script as follows. I created a VBScript program named `SuccessorML.vbs` with the code:

```
Set WS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WS.RUN("sml -Cparser.succ-ml=true")
```

and put the icon in the folder that I usually program in. When I click it an instance of the SML REPL with the successor features already enabled pops up. I already have the path to sml on my system's path. If you don't -- you would have to add the full path in the run command.

On Windows the command `sml` links to a small `.bat` file. You could probably edit that file so it opens sml with `succ-ml` enabled -- by I like the idea of being able to easily launch SML either way.